# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

When I run  `npm start`
I get

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
```

This happens after I have run

```
npm install
```

I tried to solve the issue by running  `npm -g install npm@version` but instead it gave me this error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@version.
```

Comment: It seems to be npm versioning problem. Watch this: https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/608

Comment: But when I check the logs am told {error code ELIFECYCLE}

Answer (score 9):

Did you just upgrade your dependencies directly from 3.0?
In v4 `eslint` is required as a dependency of the project itself.
So `npm install --save-dev eslint@4` may fix the warning.

Comment: Thank you! Also, `eslint-plugin-vue` is required.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience it may happen if there is import of `package.json` in one of your project's files, but with incorrect path.
Usually, some build related configurations use `version` property of the `package.json`.
It is hard to pinpoint the exact issue, since no specifics provided.
First, I'd search stack trace of the error to locate which file is requesting `package.json`. Global project search for `.version` should help to find the issue as well.

If you still unable to locate the issue, please, add full error stack trace.